# How can i solve prblem with closing Tabs C#

Tags: c#

I codes function for auto closing Tab.However there is some problem with error with calling Dispose function. Do you know how it can be easily fixed?

During error it says:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Value Dispose() cannot be called while doing CreateHandle().
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at TabContent.TabContentControl.Dispose(Boolean disposing) in c:\Users\User\Desktop\Trading Panel\Trading Panel\TabContent\TabContentControl.Designer.cs:line 20
   at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.ComponentModel.Component.Dispose()
   at cAlgo.Panel.HandlePositionClosed(PositionClosedEventArgs args) in c:\Users\User\Desktop\Trading Panel\Sources\Robots\PanelOriginal\PanelOriginal\Panel.cs:line 349
```

Code is

```
  private void HandlePositionClosed(PositionClosedEventArgs args)
         {
            if (_robot.PositionsByLabel.All(x => x.SymbolName != args.Position.SymbolName))
            {
                var customTab = _customTabs
                    .ToList()
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text.Contains(args.Position.SymbolName));

                if (customTab != null)
                {
                    
                    tabControl1.Controls.Remove(customTab);
                    customTab.Dispose();
                    _customTabs.Remove(customTab);
                    
                }
            }
        }


protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Most likely a threading race bug, nobody can see the Begin/Invoke() call that caused it.   You must ensure that no such call is made until the form's Load event fired.

Comment: Try switching the lines `customTab.Dispose();` and `_customTabs.Remove(customTab);` - Dispose should be the last thing you do with the object